# Giving AD user accounts admin access on specific machines

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, users, permissions

Is there a way to give domain based accounts administrative access on specific machines and not others?

I can control access and rights to which machines a user can log in to and what their privileges are on a global scale but is there a way to control them on individual machines?

Comment: Q: Is there a way to give domain based accounts administrative access on specific machines and not others? A: Yes. Add the domain accounts to the local Administrators group on the desired machines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

You can add domain accounts to individual machines, and into whatever groups you want on individual machines as well.  On a [manual, one-off basis](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739265%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (for example, `NET LOCALGROUP Administrators [domain]\[account] /ADD`), programmatically [with a script](http://ss64.com/nt/net_useradmin.html), or even [using Group Policy to handle it dynamically](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731972.aspx) and automatically.

Comment: +1 for the clean, simple answer that also has a nice flow to it with the links...

Answer (score 1):

Add them to the local administrators group on the individual machines.  If you want to manage this centrally then add a domain security group per machine/group of machines enabling you to add/remove members of those groups in active directory.